# webpack require is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, rabbitmq

Im trying to implement a rabbitmq client in my react project. this is my code so far:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api').default();
var topics;
export class rabbitMq{
  constructor(topics_Subs){
    topics = topics_Subs;
  }
  conntectRabit(){
    amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {});
  }
}
```

but Im getting this error: _webpack_require__(...).connect is not a function, the thing is that if I make a console.log(typeof(amqp.connect)) this is telling that connect is a function, I have no idea what is happening. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Instead of require, can you switch to import statement and try this?

Comment: I have tried with : import amqp from 'amqplib/callback_api'; with no success,  :(

Comment: whats that .default() doing in your first line? could not find anything about it in the docs. have you tried it without the .default() ?

Comment: Sorry, the .default() is not in my actual code, I read than in some forum, so far I have tried with: var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api'); and import amqp from 'amqplib/callback_api';, but the error is the same :(

Comment: it could that a library problem. Are you sure that you are importing the correct module? This doesn't look like a webpack problem

Comment: Im pretty sure thats the correct library, Im taking the code from here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html